# A two valued measure forms an ultrafilter

Tags: measure-theory, filters

I've got stuck in verifying that for a two valued measure $\mu$ this forms an ultrafilter:

$$U=\{X\subseteq S:\mu(X)=1\}$$

E.g. why if $X\in U$ and $Y\in U$ then $X\cap Y\in U$ ?

Comment: Try this: More generally, in any probability space, if $\mu(X) = \mu(Y) = 1$ then $\mu(X \cap Y) = 1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $μ(X\cap Y)=0$ it means $μ(X\setminus Y)=1$, but if $μ(X\setminus Y)=1$ then $μ((X\setminus Y)∪Y)=μ(X\setminus Y)+μ(Y)=2$, which is impossible by the definition of two-valued measure.

Comment: Please why $\mu(X\cap Y)=0$ implies $\mu(X\setminus Y)=1$ ?

Comment: @user122424 $X\cap Y$ and $X\setminus Y$ are disjoint so $μ(X\cap Y)+μ(X\setminus Y)=μ((X\cap Y)∪(X\setminus Y))=μ(X)=1$